Geometric interpretation of trace of a linear operator
This question is really an addendum to Geometric interpretation of trace
There is a nice account of the trace in Chris Doran's thesis here: http://geometry.mrao.cam.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/DoranThesis.pdf
page 135, Eq. (5.13).  The definition is in terms of a directional derivative. This aligns well with the reference given to V.I. Arnold quoted by Sujit_Nair (https://mathoverflow.net/users/4373/sujit-nair).
(Had only 10 reputation, so could not post to the original.)
Q. Does anyone have a derivation for a matrix trace (or any other linear operator formalism) that goes from Doran's definition (in the Clifford algebra) to the other formalism?

Okay, let me see if I've understood what all this notation means, with the help of the Wikipedia article. Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional real inner product space and let $F : V \to \text{Cl}(V)$ be a smooth function from $V$ to its Clifford algebra. Let $e_i$ be a basis of $V$ and let $e^i$ be its dual basis with respect to the inner product, so $e^i \cdot e_j = \delta_{ij}$. Then the $e_i$ define directional derivatives
$$\partial_i F : V \ni v \mapsto \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{F(v + t e_i) - F(v)}{\varepsilon} \in \text{Cl}(V)$$
and these assemble into a single gadget called the vector derivative
$$\partial_v : \text{Smooth}(V, \text{Cl}(V)) \ni F \mapsto \sum e^i \partial_i F \in \text{Smooth}(V, \text{Cl}(V)).$$
Since this is defined in terms of the Clifford product and since the Clifford product with a vector breaks up into an inner product (which lowers degree by $1$) and an exterior product (which increases degree by $1$), the vector derivative can be written as the sum of the corresponding operations (Doran never defines these but fortunately Wikipedia does)
$$\partial_v \cdot (-) : F \mapsto \sum e^i \cdot \partial_i F$$
$$\partial_v \wedge (-) : F \mapsto \sum e^i \wedge \partial_i F.$$
To check this let's test our understanding so far against the identities in (5.10) on p. 135. We have that
$$\partial_v (v \cdot w) = \sum e^i (e_i \cdot w) = w$$
which is fine. Next,
$$\partial_v v^2 = \sum e^i (2v \cdot e_i) = 2v$$
which is fine. Next, and this is important because it's notation we need to interpret to compute the trace,
$$\partial_v \cdot v = \sum e^i \cdot e_i = n$$
as expected. Okay, finally Doran's definition of the trace amounts to the following: if $f : V \to V$ is a linear map then
$$\boxed{ \text{tr}(f) = \partial_v \cdot f(v) = \sum e^i \cdot f(e_i) }$$
which is not new, this is just a slight variant of "sum of the diagonal entries." As far as I can tell the underline notation $\underline{f}$ he uses here is irrelevant; in Chapter 1 he defines this to refer to the extension of a linear map $f$ to blades via the exterior product but since we are taking the vector derivative here only the action of $f$ on vectors matters! At first I was trying to figure out if he was taking the derivative of $\det$ somehow but nope.
Whether this gives some geometric insight into the trace is unclear to me. Arnold's quote is about taking the derivative of $\det$ (which is the most geometric interpretation I'm aware of for the trace) and whether these two can be directly related is also unclear to me.

Can the downvoter explain? Have I made an error somewhere?
